# Why is auto not allowed in lambda parameter?

Tags: c++, lambda, auto

When I write a lambda definition with the following signature:

```
auto lambda = [&] (auto i){


};
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
error: 'auto' not allowed in lambda parameter
```

When I change the type from `auto` to `int`, the error disappears.

I am not sure why the compiler can deduce the type of a lambda, but not its parameter type, which should be known to it at the time of the invocation of the lambda?

I am trying to understand the reasoning behind this restriction.

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: Compile as C++14 at the very least.

Comment: Generic lambdas are C++14 and later. Your compiler is apparently working in C++11 mode.

Comment: Note that with that definition `lambda(5); lambda(5.5); lambda("foo");` are all valid calls.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I am not sure why the compiler can deduce the type of a lambda, but
>   not its parameter type, which should be known to it at the time of the
>   invocation of the lambda?

It can, but only since *C++14*.

```
auto lambda = [&] (auto i) { };
```

This code is perfectly legal since *C++14* and called *generic lambda*.

Unfortunately, *generic lambdas* are not available before *C++14*, so, if you need to use them, *C++14* support is required.